# Returning an array in case switching C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to return an array with a date `[sStartMonth, sStartDay, sStartYear]` for a specific case, for example:  `case: "Today"` will return `{"June", "3", "2015"}`.

I am trying something like this but fail:

```
public static string[] SetStartDate(string sStartDateFilter)
    {
        switch (sStartDateFilter)
        {
            case "Today":
                DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
                string sStartMonth = currentDate.ToString("MMMM");
                string sStartDay = currentDate.Day.ToString();
                string sStartYear = currentDate.Year.ToString();
                return {sStartMonth, sStartDay, sStartYear};               
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should consider your naming conventions. A method called **Set** anything should not *just return* something. It should really *set* something.

Comment: What is it exactly that fails? What's the output or compile error?

Comment: In the future you should also get into the habit of posting what the "fail" part is, and where it is located, such as pointing out the compiler error you get and which line you get it on. Other than that your question was really well formed.

Comment: You are correct Lasse, didn't think the naming through..

Comment: You should also try to work in a semi-ISO convention of [Year, Month, Day], rather than [Month, Day,Year]. It's just a good habit to get into.

Comment: It's just fitting the order of elements I see in the GUI.. Prefer it to look this way

Answer (score 7):

To construct an array in-line you need the full syntax, the short-hand syntax you're using is only allowed when explicitly declaring an array and giving it a value in the same statement.

So this is what you want:

```
return new[] { sStartMonth, sStartDay, sStartYear };
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
    switch (sStartDateFilter)
    {
        case "Today":
           return new[] { sStartMonth, sStartDay, sStartYear };

        default:
           // return something here or throw
```

You will need to return something for the default case too, or throw a `new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("sStartDateFilter")` or you will get a compiler error as not all paths will return a value.

Comment: Yep, that's what I did! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To combine the answer of `@Lasse V. Karlsen` with my potential answer:

```
public static string[] GetStartDate(string sStartDateFilter)
{
    DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;

    switch (sStartDateFilter)
    {
        case "Today":
            return new string[]{ currentDate.ToString("MMMM"), currentDate.Day.ToString(), currentDate.Year.ToString()};
        case "Tomorrow":
            currentDate.AddDays(1);

            return new string[]{ currentDate.ToString("MMMM"), currentDate.Day.ToString(), currentDate.Year.ToString()};
        case "Yesterday":
            currentDate.AddDays(-1);

            return new string[]{ currentDate.ToString("MMMM"), currentDate.Day.ToString(), currentDate.Year.ToString()};
        default:
            // all other cases
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

I know, that I should move the line `return new string[]{ currentDate.ToString("MMMM"), currentDate.Day.ToString(), currentDate.Year.ToString()};` into a separate function, but this is only a simple example

Comment: Ah dang, this is beautiful. Thanks!